# Contenteditable changes not seen on other devices with browsersync

Tags: javascript, html, browser-sync

I wish to make text changes in a content editable div sync with browsersync.
I've created a simple teleprompter and my content editable div is where i paste my script on the host machine.

Unfortunately this pasted text is not synced to other screens :(

Anyone can push me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you show us some code and describe the problem a bit more in details?

Comment: I've figured it out after some more thought. Just pasting text into a content editable div doesn't make it sync across devices. The solution was to save/store that text (i used localstorage) and then it will show up on the other devices (ipad and iphone).